why doesn't eloquent's eager loading work with a newly created model
Just out of interest, because I can work around it, does anyone know why with doesn't filter items to match a newly created model? Let me explain.
I have a model with the following relationship on my Transaction model.
    public function splits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Split::class);
    }

Given a transaction with an $id,
Transaction::where('id', $id)->with('splits')->get()

correctly returns only the splits related to transaction with $id.
Transaction::find($id)->with('splits')->get()

on the other hand returns all splits. I understand this is because find is left until last in eloquent's processes. That's strange to me, but I've learned to live with it.
Even stranger, now, is that if I create a transaction and associated split
$t = Transaction::create(data);
$s = Split::create(['transaction_id' => $t->id]);

and try to eager load the relationship
$t->with('splits')->get()

once again returns all splits in the database, rather than filtering for matches with $t.
I can work around this with
Transaction::where('transaction_id', $t->id)->with('splits')->get()

but I'd love to know why the simpler version doesn't work.
